# How to stop a high torque stepper motor when a certain amount of load is applied?

Tags: motor, sensor, stepper-motor, strain-gage

I’m looking for some design suggestions for stopping the linear actuation of a platform when too much load is applied to the moving plate, for both normal and axial loads. I mainly do not want to choke the motor or for anyone else possibly using this system to be hurt if it won’t stop. Ideally, if something were to go wrong, the entire system wouldn’t be damage and would just need a reset/restart.

I am considering using a NEMA 17/23 stepper motor with a lead screw & guide rails or a belt & pulley system. I’m not quite sure which offers better safety and reliability with stopping the motor. At first thought, it seems that the lead screw would generate torsion to the point of breaking or damaging some other hardware. Perhaps the pulley can slip under too much load?

Is it customary to use other sensors, such as strain gage, to detect overloading or misuse? TIA.

Comment: Check out how car manufacturers do it with electric windows - merest resistance and they stop and reverse...

Comment: My Merc SUV just skips steps when it stops moving the tailgate with the fast ticking sound, thus a current limited torque

Comment: Also consider a mechanical break-away - something that "gives" under too much torque, and would be easy to reset (or self-resets.)

Comment: @Solar Mike Thank you for this. I read through two patents and some explanation articles I found online. Many detect a speed change in the motor due to added force. Wondering how feasible that approach is for higher torque motors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Prusa printer uses [Trinamic drivers](https://www.trinamic.com/technology/motor-control-technology/stallguard-and-coolstep/) for its steppers. These have configurable overload detection- something they call StallGuard- that looks at motor current for detecting stalls/load. [Here's a PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiPldPRi53yAhXQB80KHbiRALkQFnoECAQQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.trinamic.com%2F_scripts%2Fdownload.php%3Ffile%3D_articles%252Fsupport%252Fwebinars%252F_webinars%252F2009-03_stallGuard_with_videos.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ADWQa2JO1r9ruwnU0GGRD) that discusses the StallGuard feature. [Here's an overview](https://blog.adafruit.com/2020/06/18/eye-on-npi-tmc2226-sa-ultra-silent-stepper-motor-driver-eyeonnpi-digikey-adafruit-digikey-adafruit-trinamic_mc/) on Adafruit that discusses one of the Trinamic chips...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am seriously considering these chips now.